# Ruby on Rails total in table footer

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a pretty simple form as I'm just really playing with RoR at the moment, just collecting some data and plunking it in the DB, nothing exciting just basic CRUD.  However, I am wanting to put a sum field in the footer of my table, but I'm not finding anything even close on the web.  Is this not possible in RoR?  Seems like a pretty simplistic task, but I'm sure my noobiness in Rails isn't helping matters anyway. :)

```
<tbody>
    <% @labors.each do |labor| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= labor.employee %></td>
        <td><%= labor.item_no %></td>
        <td><%= labor.customer_number %></td>
        <td><%= labor.customer_name %></td>
        <td><%= labor.total_labor %></td>
        <td><%= labor.burden %></td>
        <td><%= labor.hours %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', labor %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_labor_path(labor) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', labor, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td>Sum</td>
        <td><%= @labors.map{|item| item.val}.reduce{0, :+} %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
```

Keep getting a syntax error caused by the ','.

```
app/views/labors/index.html.erb:35: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting '}'
```

Comment: You will need to edit your index view and add a new row at the bottom (<tr><td>...</td></tr>). Add a colspan attribute to that <td> containing the number of columns you have in your table.

Inside that column use ```<%= @my_objects_list.size %>``` to print out the number of objects you have. This is assuming the name of your objects list retrieved in the index action is ```@my_objects_list```, and that you're using erb template engine.

Comment: @RotemHarel Thanks I should have been more specific on wanting a total of the value not the number of entries, but I will keep this in mind when I need it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data is in an array `@items` and each item includes a value attribute 'val', then after your loop to render the items, add another table row like

```
<tr>
  <td>Sum</td>
  <td><%= @lobors.map{|item| item.total_labor}.reduce(0, :+) %></td>
</tr>
```

`map`is used to extract the value you want to sum, `reduce` is used to calculate the sum of an array.

Comment: Thanks man I'll give this a shot tomorrow when I'm at work. I appreciate the quick response.

Comment: Getting a syntax error complaining about the comma after the 0.  See my edit.

Comment: @MartinM, I had to put the new answer with the right set of brackets :) after noticing you had chosen wrong brackets in your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
<td><%= @labors.map{|item| item.val}.reduce{0, :+} %></td>
```

to

```
<td><%= @labors.map{|item| item.val}.reduce(0, :+) %></td>
```

Hope this works for you!

Cheers!

Comment: aha that was part of the answer.  See my answer below. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so these were spot on with how this would work. Let me break down how I got there:

My code:

```
<tbody>
    <% @labors.each do |labor| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= labor.employee %></td>
        <td><%= labor.item_no %></td>
        <td><%= labor.customer_number %></td>
        <td><%= labor.customer_name %></td>
        <td><%= labor.total_labor %></td>
        <td><%= labor.burden %></td>
        <td><%= labor.hours %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', labor %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_labor_path(labor) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', labor, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td>Sum</td>
        <td><%= @labors.map{|item| item.val}.reduce{0, :+} %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
```

Ok so originally this was the code that @Martin suggested, I kept getting an error about the  ','. So @Pamio suggested that I put the '0, :+' in () and then I got a .val error. Which actually led me into the solution.

The .val will have to be the actual field that you are wanting to total, I suspect this is because it is in an array and well there is no value for .val in most cases.  So, the code ended up like this:

```
    <tbody>
    <% @labors.each do |labor| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= labor.employee %></td>
        <td><%= labor.item_no %></td>
        <td><%= labor.customer_number %></td>
        <td><%= labor.customer_name %></td>
        <td><%= labor.total_labor %></td>
        <td><%= labor.burden %></td>
        <td><%= labor.hours %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', labor %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_labor_path(labor) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', labor, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>

    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
<h3>Sum</h3>
<div><span>Total Labor: </span><%= @labors.map{|item| item.total_labor}.reduce(0, :+) %></div>
```

Notice the change of item.val to item.total_labor the actual field name that I want to total.   Thanks for the insight, I appreciate it.

Edited in a slight change in formatting.. my original post was adding a total field every time it looped. :) oops!